# Raster calc function - issue with NA data

Tags: r, function, raster

I am trying to apply a relatively simple 'raster math' computation between two rasters. I can't seem to figure out how to set NA values properly in my function. I've looked everywhere for an answer and tried a few different ways to solve this but to no avail.

```
library(raster)

#Edited with feedback
fun.calc <- function(x, y, ...)
{
tree.w <- sum(x / (100 - y), ...)
ifelse(is.na(x) | is.na(y), NA, tree.w)
}

r1 <- raster(nrow=50, ncol = 50)
r1[] <- 90
r1[4:10,] <- NA
r2 <- raster(nrow=50, ncol = 50)
r2[] <- 40
r2[9:15,] <- NA

#Try UPDATED
fun.calc(r1[,,1], r2[,,1], fun=fun.calc, na.rm=TRUE)
```

This doesn't thrown an error, but I do not get the correct values, which should be 1.5 everywhere that there are no NA values (I get 2850). I don't understand why this is doing this, but I imagine it has something to do with the vectors in the raster.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Where is the function `raster()` coming from. Please include all necessary libraries with your code.

Comment: Sorry @MrFlick, edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I had to do this to get a solution to this answer. I don't really understand why except for that this seems to work. If anyone has a better answer, that would be great.

```
fun.calc1 <- function(x, y, ...)
{
tree.w <- sum(x / (100 - y), ...)
length.xy <- length(which(!is.na(x) & !is.na(y)))
ifelse(is.na(x) | is.na(y), NA, tree.w/length.xy)
}

fun.calc1(r1[1:length(r1)],r2[1:length(r2)], na.rm=T)
```

Again, not sure why it works but I do get the correct answer of 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat, I can tell you that `fun.calc1` should be re-written to something like I have below.  You have too many `return` statements, when in fact you don't really need them at all. You also didn't pass the `...` argument into the function.  I also don't really understand why you would want `na.rm = TRUE` if you want `NA` returned if it's in `x` or `y`.

```
fun.calc1 <- function(x, y, ...)
{
     tree.w <- sum(x / (100 - y), ...)
     ifelse(is.na(x) | is.na(y), NA, tree.w)
}
```

Yielding

```
> fun.calc1(5, 10)
# [1] 0.05555556
> fun.calc1(5, NA, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] NA
```

Which is the same as

```
fun.calc3 <- function(x, y)  sum(x / (100 - y))

> fun.calc1(5, 10)
# [1] 0.05555556    
> fun.calc3(5, NA)
# [1] NA
```

Comment: Yes, @Richard Scriven I am still learning about functions! I see that the first works with the vector example data but with the raster examples I get the following error:
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) :
  cannot use this function. Perhaps add '...' or 'na.rm' to the function arguments?